# Why is Kanata Age considered a traitor?

Tags: sky-wizards-academy

Throughout the series he's called a traitor, in episode 9 around the 16min mark Yuri internalizes "how can he be so at peace knowing he betrayed us and became a coward"  So is he considered a traitor for leaving their ranks?

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. This question has been asked and answered before, consider reading it :)